# Limit Text Inside Div and Display OnHover

Tags: overflow, onhover

I'm trying to limit the text inside div using height and overflow:hidden, but then I want to display the full text on hover, but the hover section is not being displayed or being cut due to the overflow:hidden.

How can I fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/2e7mqruf/

```
<div  class="tooltip-pr" style="max-width: 220px;">
SOME LONG TEXT TO DISPLAY ON HOVER
<span class="tooltiptext-pr">
SOME LONG TEXT TO DISPLAY ON HOVER
</span>
</div>



.tooltip-pr {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid;
}
.tooltip-pr .tooltiptext-pr {
visibility: hidden;
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
}
.tooltip-pr:hover .tooltiptext-pr {
visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solves your problem. To display the full text I'm changing the height here, `white-space:nowrap` wraps the text in a text line, which is why we used the `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow:ellipsis` adds 3 dots at the end of the text pointing if your text overflows it will add those dots, lastly hyphens properly adjusts your text within the div element. you can tweak it however you want.

```css
.tooltip-pr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.tooltip-pr .tooltiptext-pr {
  //visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.tooltip-pr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  white-space: initial;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-pr">
  <span class="tooltiptext-pr">
    SOME LONG TEXT TO DISPLAY ON HOVER
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. nice solution, but the issue is that it increase the main div height, which I choose to limit due to other elements in the page, so I don't want to increase it. I actually just removed "position: relative;" from my code and it seems working fine

Comment: Alright if it works then its fine, and as you said you don't want to increase the main div height because of the elements, then you can set all the child elements position absolute making the main div position relative. This way the child elements height will not affect the main div element. Hope this solves your problem and if so, please do accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tooltip-pr {
  max-width: 220px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.tooltip-pr .tooltiptext-pr {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.tooltip-pr:hover .tooltiptext-pr {
  visibility: visible;
}
.tooltip-pr:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-pr">
  SOME LONG TEXT TO DISPLAY ON HOVER
  <span class="tooltiptext-pr">
    SOME LONG TEXT TO DISPLAY ON HOVER
  </span>
</div>
```